# ionic cordova IO exception while downloading manifest

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, ionic-framework, android-manifest

When I try building my ionic project using `ionic cordova build android` I get the following error:

```
IO exception while downloading manifest:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-desktop/sys-img2-1.xml
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1890)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:263)
        at com.android.sdklib.repository.legacy.remote.internal.DownloadCache.openUrl(DownloadCache.java:248)
        at com.android.sdklib.repository.legacy.remote.internal.DownloadCache.downloadAndCache(DownloadCache.java:624)
        at com.android.sdklib.repository.legacy.remote.internal.DownloadCache.openCachedUrl(DownloadCache.java:547)
        at com.android.sdklib.repository.legacy.LegacyDownloader.downloadAndStream(LegacyDownloader.java:61)
        at com.android.repository.impl.downloader.LocalFileAwareDownloader.downloadAndStream(LocalFileAwareDownloader.java:51)
        at com.android.repository.impl.manager.RemoteRepoLoaderImpl.lambda$fetchPackages$0(RemoteRepoLoaderImpl.java:139)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Still waiting for package manifests to be fetched remotely.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Failed to find Build Tools revision 33.0.0-rc2
```

If I try to access the xml URL from second line above, its showing 404 page. Also, I have
build tool `33.0.0-rc2` in my Android dir.

I am getting similar results when i run `sdkmanager` command in CMD

```
Warning: java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-desktop/sys-img2-1.xml
[=======================================] 100% Computing updates...
```

**ionic info**

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 6.19.0 (C:\Users\CGauns\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v16.15.0\node_modules\@ionic\cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.5.2
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.1100.4
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 10.0.8
   @angular/cli                  : 10.0.8
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 3.0.0

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 11.0.0
   Cordova Platforms : android 9.0.0
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 5.0.0, (and 35 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : 0.15.4
   native-run  : 1.5.0

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (D:\Android\sdk)
   NodeJS            : v16.15.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm               : 8.5.5
   OS                : Windows 10
```

It looks like that file `sys-img2-1.xml` is removed or something.

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed this for me by updating Cordova from v10 to v11.

I see you're listing v11 in your question, but maybe there's something to it. Try running `which cordova` together with your build command to make sure you're utilizing the right cordova version.